# how to use couchbase.lite with link sdks only option in Xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, couchbase-lite

Now I am using Couchbase.Lite in iOS project, but it throws an error with Initialising in Linker Option with link sdks only, 
Anybody has this kind of problem before?
But with don't link option, it works okay.
In this case, we can deduce the ipa size to publish app in App Store.
Can you help me out, if you faced this kind of problem before.
Thanks,

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please post the verbose build output and/or any error messages: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs

Comment: This is a known issue with the current Xamarin framework version.  The only solution is to set the Don't link option as you have done.

Comment: thanks for your time, and letting me know, then what can you recommend to reduce the binary size?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36255. Its been worked on.

The workaround for now will be to use "-nolinkaway" as this will only have a minimal increase in the final app size, unlike "dont link sdk".